# Reading a recursive field on post_save of django model

Tags: python, django, recursion, foreign-key-relationship

I'm using signals to save log from table inserts. I created a model using recursive field, but when I use this field on post_save def, this is returning None value.

My model:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False)
    manager = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True) #Recursive field

signals.post_save.connect(add_history_member, sender=Member)
```

My signal def:

```
def add_history_member(sender, instance, signal, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        item = MemberHistory(name_user=instance.user.first_name)

        if instance.manager: #this ruturns None
            item.name_manager = instance.manager.first_name

        item.save()
```

I have no idea why this problem is occurring.

Comment: Does the particular model has a self.manager after it is saved? I.e. is it a problem on the signal or on the creation?